# The weight of a 2cc glass pharmaceutical flame sealed ampoule?

Tags: equipment

This is one of the flame sealed type whose neck is broken before use. There seems to be lots of info on dimensions but none with regard to weight.

Comment: Break one and weigh. Note that there is not much sense in weighing to a greater accuracy than grams because every ampoule will have a different weight; these weights will differ *at least* by tens of milligrams if not by hundreds.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have one, and I do not want to buy a big batch just to weigh one.

Comment: Why do you need its weight then?

Comment: To attach to a microbalance that is mass limited and to weight in gas to determine gas density. Volume would be found by calibrating with gases of known density at a given temperature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grabbed 10 empty, unsealed ones and threw them on the analytical balance and got mean: 2.4071 g, s.d.: 0.01264 g for Wheaton amber glass pre-scored vials (part number 176796). The variation between vials isn't too bad, but I don't know if they can be filled and sealed consistently enough to determine gas density like that to any useful precision and other brands may be better or worse.

Comment: $+1$ for ‘I don't know if they can be filled and sealed consistently enough to determine gas density like that *to any useful precision’*

Comment: Think buoyancy...